# JQuery: Perform a post before a link is followed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I need to do an asynchronous post to a server when someone on my site clicks a link. I tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to be doing the task on the server I want it to. I think the problem is that it is following the link before something can happen. I don't actually need to wait for the response back from the server, I just need it to send the call to it. Can anyone help me out? Maybe how to delay following the link before it is called or should I be note using $.post?

```
$("#item").click(function (ev) {
    $.post(link_to_something);
});

<a id="item" href="www.google.com">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is to cancel the default action of the link by returning false from the `click` handler. This will allow enough time for the AJAX request to complete. And when it completes, inside the success callback you could redirect to wherever the link is pointing to:

```
$("#item").click(function (ev) {
    var self = this;
    $.post(link_to_something, function() {
        window.location.href = self.href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the response to determine whether the post has been succeeded or not then you should go on.

```
$("#item").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(link_to_something, function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```