# Unable to trigger Ajax click function in Django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

Trying to update a model based on which download link was pressed in Django.

Please see current code below, so fair it doesn't appear to be logging to console either.

**From profile.html**

```
{% for x in source %}
    {% if forloop.counter <= 4 %}
      <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{ x.video_id }}</h2>
        {% for y in records %}
          {% if x.video_id == y.sourcevideo.video_id %}
            <div class="media-body">
              <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src="{{ y.highlight.url }}" type="video/mp4">
                  Your browser does not support the video tag
                </video>
                <br>
                <a class="btn" id="download" href="{{ y.highlight.url }}" data-id="{{ y.highlight_id }}" download>Download</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#download").click(function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr("data-id") );
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/downloaded",
        data: {
              highlight_id: catid
            },
        success: function( data )  {
          console.log(data)
        }
      })
   })
  </script>
```

**From views.py**

```
def downloaded(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        highlight_id = request.GET('highlight_id')
        downloadedvideo = Highlight.objects.get(pk=highlight_id)
        downloadedvideo.used = True
        downloadedvideo.save()
        return
    else:
        return
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', UploadVideo.as_view(), name='upload'),
    path(r'^downloaded/$', views.downloaded, name='downloaded'),
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Updated profile.html**
This is the updated profile following the instructions from here: [JQuery: Perform a post before a link is followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256916/jquery-perform-a-post-before-a-link-is-followed)

```
     {% if forloop.counter <= 4 %}
      <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{ x.video_id }}</h2>
        {% for y in records %}
          {% if x.video_id == y.sourcevideo.video_id %}
            <div class="media-body">
              <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src="{{ y.highlight.url }}" type="video/mp4">
                  Your browser does not support the video tag
                </video>
                <br>
                <a class="btn" class="download" href="{{ y.highlight.url }}" data-id="{{ y.highlight_id }}" download>Download</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".download").click(function(ev) {
    var self = this;
    $post.('/downloaded', function() {
      window.location.href = self.href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

**From Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Highlight(models.Model): #record of each HIGHLIGHT video, derived from a SOURCE video
    highlight_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    sourcevideo = models.ForeignKey(Video, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    highlight = models.FileField(upload_to = 'highlights/')
    max_energy = models.IntegerField()
    average_energy = models.IntegerField()
    highlight_length = models.IntegerField()
    quality = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: You shouldn’t have multiple elements with the same id. Try using a class instead. You should follow the advice in this question as to how to perform a post before a link is followed https://stackoverflow.com/q/9256916/548562

Comment: Thanks Iain, updated to a class with the advice linked however I'm still not recording the boolean change through to the database. Included updated code in the op.

Answer (score 0):

In your `views.py` file you are using `request.GET` instead of `request.POST`

Since there are no GET requests, your view is returning None.

It should look like this:

```
def downloaded(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        highlight_id = request.POST('highlight_id')
        downloadedvideo = Highlight.objects.get(pk=highlight_id)
        downloadedvideo.used = True
        downloadedvideo.save()
        return
    else:
        return
```

Comment: this makes sense and have now updated, unfortunately I'm still not seeing the database update.

Comment: Can you add your models.py?  I'll try to do a quick mockup of your case.  Also, have you tried to print out `highlight_id` and see what prints in your console?

Comment: I've tried adding a print command it's not triggering which implies the post signal isn't getting to the function. I've gone ahead and added the models.py and urls.py